# How to correctly use readWave in Rstudio

Tags: r, tuner

Im getting this error while executing this line in RStudio, I have tuneR lib installed.

```
birds <- readWave("birds.wav")
```

> Error in readBin(con, int, n = 4, size = 1, endian = "little", signed = FALSE) %*%  :
> non-conformable arguments
> In addition: Warning message:
> In readChar(con, 4, useBytes = TRUE) : truncating string with embedded nuls

Tried to look for examples and can´t find any that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar error message, but without warning:

```
FILENAME = "FILENAME.wav"
Soundfile = readWave(FILENAME)
```

"Error in readBin(con, int, n = 4, size = 1, endian = "little", signed = FALSE) %*%  :
non-conformable arguments"

In my case, the problem was that the file size is 0 octets:

```
file.info(FILENAME)$size
[1] 0
```

So I added this before reading so I won't have an error again because of empty files:

```
if(file.info(FILENAME)$size !=0){
          Soundfile = readWave(FILENAME)
        }else{
          warning(paste0(FILENAME, " has size of 0 octets"))
        }
```

Comment: I have the same error but with a non-empty file that Audacity can open